# Angular and input type Date won't display date assigned in format with T

Tags: angular, typescript, date, input

I have application in Angular 8, I have input type date binded with property Date from object in Angular:

```
 <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="day.dayValue"  class="form-control" [disabled]="false"/>
```

And the DayDTO object in TypeScript:

```
export class DayDTO {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  dayValue: Date;
}
```

When I set value in this input by hand the property `dayValue` is set.
But when I want to set input type text by assigning:

```
this.day.dayValue = res.dayValue
```

when dayValue comes from controller written in .NET Core:
[image: dayValue in format T]

the input type Date isn't set.
When I remove T00:00:00 in string, the input type Date is set

---

Only works when I remove `T00:00:00`
[image: without T]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the date Pipe in your date input

Like this

```js
"day.dayValue | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
```

Full code [Edited]

```html
<input
  type="date"
  [(ngModel)]="day.dayValue"
  [ngModel]="day.dayValue | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
  [disabled]="false"
/> />
```

**Notice that I added both `[ngModel]` and `[(ngModel])`**

You can take this and place it instead of your input and it will work.

Comment: Doesn't work: Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 16 in [day.dayValue | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'=$event]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatly doesn't work too :(

Comment: Hey, sorry for that, here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5ggggu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for an example, it worked.

Notice that the order of the attributes in the date input is matter.